# Regex matchs the whole string when I make a break

Tags: regex, echo

I have a problem with my regex, which should detect all `echo` functions in a string. So right now I have this expression:

```
/echo(.|\n)*?\(?"(.|\n)*"\)?;/g
```

This works until you make a break line in the quotes. If you do that, it would match the whole code until the end, as you can see in the picture:

[image: RegExr Image]

You can get it [here](https://regexr.com/3h6e4).

What did I wrong? What do I have to change?

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)`, use `[\s\S]` if you are not sure DOTALL modifier can be used.

Comment: I now use the following regex to detect it. `/echo(.|\n)*?\(?"*"\)?;/g`. I just removed the dot and the `\n` between the brackets.

Comment: Replace `(.|\n)` with `[\s\S]` and you will have the same functionality at faster speed. You will also start matching a CR symbol.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But then it still does the same like `(.|\n)`. Or can you send me a full regex?

Comment: `(.|\n)*?` is a performance killer. NEVER, NEVER use it unless you are using ElasticSearch regex.